# non-xml Android views

Tags: android, view

Trying to program a connect4 style game in Android and running into issues with the views. I have worked with Java AWT and am trying to get the same functionality out of Android. A simple drawing system by which I can update the game board and have the screen remain until a button press causes a change to the game board.
I have tried looking at a few tutorials but most tend to go the XML route which I am less familiar with, and also it seems it would be harder to update each of the game board locations using XML.
Any easy to understand tutorials or specific instructions would be really helpful.
Really just looking for a way to specify locations within a view by pixel location since that makes the most sense in my mind. if there are far easier ways those would be appreciated.

Comment: @user560094: Firstly, can you provide an image (even a mock-up graphic) for the sort of 'board' layout you're envisaging? Secondly are you looking for animations? As for XML layouts, they're generally used for initial views rather than something like 'in-game' usage.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is drawing directly on a given canvas. The official site got the [resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html) you need.

Comment: what I'm looking to do is layout a background color (yellow) and overlay that at evenly spaced locations to show the pieces with seperate colors for player1 player2, and a third color for empty spaces. That will be without animations just pieces appearing in the right spots when they are chosen. Looking at the link by xandy the use of shape drawing seems doable but how then do I make the shapes change in relation to my code for what color they should be?

Comment: The link actually covers from shape drawables to even lower-level lines and pixels drawing techniques.